# inline-block list items mess up when one is empty

Tags: html, css

I wanted to put some image in first list item but it seems to mess up when it's no content. i tried various methods in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/plastic1111/6pewkjd3/2/) (various options of display and position) but none of them works to align inline al "li" when first is empty. it seems to be problem with inline property. Do enyone had such hilarious problem, and have clear solution.

PS: *ul li {display:block; float:left;}*  doesn't work

```css
ul {
  font-size: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid black 1px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  heght: 1.5em;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>

    <!--no content list item, why it mess up align to top others-->
  </li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to reset vertical-align propertie to `vertical-align:top;` *(defaut is baseline and depends on content wich sets the line-height)*

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

[examples to play with](http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/yOMWJd)

```css
ul {
  font-size: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid black 1px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  heght: 1.5em;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>

    <!--no content list item, why it mess up align to top others-->
  </li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden;` is missing into "ul li { }"

Use this:

```
ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid black 1px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. vertical-align: top; works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li {display:block; float:left;}
```

works for me.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pewkjd3/5/)